# Diference between /../*.php and *.php

Tags: php, include-path

So I had this trouble with a PHP code that I solved, but I don't really know how it works.

I tried to add this to every single file

```
<?php include '/nav.php'; ?>
```

So I can only have one file to edit the navbar instead of the whole php files.

The problem came up when I added that code to the files of another folder (ie. /general/vision.php) and I got an error (file not found). I though it was because I only hav the 'nav.php' file on the root of the site.

So, just for fun, I changed the sentence of the /general/vision.php file to

```
<?php include '../nav.php'; ?>
```

And it worked. I didn't changed the nav.php from the root, and it worked.

I'm glad it did, but I don't know why. How does that /../ works?
Is that listed on the PHP documentation?

Comment: Read up on [absolute and relative paths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`..` is OS nomenclature for "up a directory." It's nothing PHP specific.

Take a look at the concept of Relative paths.. might shed some light. [Relative paths vs Absolute paths](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/).

Answer (score 4):

`..` refers to the parent directory. This is pretty standard for all operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a server side scripting language, which means the root directory `/` is not the document root of your website, but the root of your filesystem on the server.

By beginning your path with `/` you are specifying an absolute path to the file, starting from the root. You can build a path relative from the current directory by using for example `..` to ascend one level.

You can also build an absolute path using the `__DIR__` constant in PHP, which always contains the full absolute path to the directory which contains the current PHP file, for example `include __DIR__ . '/../nav.php';`.

Answer (score 1):

While you solved your problem by having `..` (parent directory) in your include path, it is better to include the php file like this:

```
 include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/nav.php";
```

Then you can keep your PHP files anywhere in DOCUMENT_ROOT and will still be able to include this `nav.php` file.

**PS:** Its a good practice to keep common include files a level above `DOCUMENT_ROOT` so that these files cannot be directly accessed by browsers.

Comment: Actually it's good practice to not put files for inclusion under the document root of your webserver at all.

Comment: @Gary: Right I agree and have followed that practice myself.